# React Audio src is not updating on state change

Tags: reactjs, audio, use-ref

I have a list of tracks with a play button on each track which if clicked `sets(setCurrentSong hook)` the current `song(title, src, artist)` to be the song that was clicked on and toggles the `isPlaying (true, false)`.

`useEffect` fires on `[isPlaying]`, but the audio source does not update and it fails to play.

Audio tag

```
<audio ref={audioElem} src={currentSong.file}></audio>
```

Hooks and use effect.

```
const [songs, setSongs] = useState(songsdata);
const [currentSong, setcurrentSong] = useState({});
const [isplaying, setisPlaying] = useState(false)
const audioElem = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
    setcurrentSong(songs[0])
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if (isplaying) {
        audioElem.current.load()
        audioElem.current.play();
    }
    else {
        audioElem.current.pause();
    }
}, [isplaying])
```

Comment: I don't think there is enough info here to help. From the default value of `currentSong` it looks like it's a string but in your JSX you use it as an object. What is inside `songs`? Are you making changes to `songs`? If so the depedency of your first `useEffect` should have `songs` in it.

Comment: songs is an array of objects, when the page loads I set the currentSong to the first index of songs array.

Comment: Make sure `songs` is in state though if you are making changes to `songs`

Comment: const [songs, setSongs] = useState(songsdata);
    const [currentSong, setcurrentSong] = useState({});
    const [isplaying, setisPlaying] = useState(false)
    const audioElem = useRef()

Comment: The problem is when I click on a track, it sets that as the current song, and audio tag has src to be current song src. I checked components in chrome, the is playing c changes to True, and the currentSong is also set to correct clicked song, but the audio does not play, I have to click it two or three tinmes

Comment: Use the edit function to add things to your question. Code inside comments isn't very readable. From your comments I think you're bumping up against an issue that prevents music to be played via js without user interaction as a security feature of browsers. You may need to use the js API to play your source rather than re-rendering it.